# What is the particular integral of this equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$(d^2-2d+5)y=\sin x$
Particular integral of it?

Answer I am getting is $Ae^{1+2i}+Be^{1-2i}+(\cos x + 2\sin x)/10$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried? Your question will be better received by the community if you show where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Also, please format your math with MathJax. [A tutorial is here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I'll format it for you this time (just because it's Friday.) :)

Comment: Answer I am getting is Ae^(1+2i)+Be^(1-2i)+(cosx + 2sinx)/10

Comment: Are you asking about $y''-2y'+5y=\sin x$?

Comment: I just want to cross verify as I don't have the answer

Comment: Great. Please edit your question to show this. (Comments are for clarifying the question and can be deleted at any time, so putting these things in the question is preferred.)

Comment: @abiessu Yes this is the equation

Comment: @Iman Virk. You can check your result by yourself : Put it into the ODE and see it it agrees or not.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

As $\sin x$ is the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$, you can find the particular solution of your equation as the imaginary part of a particular solution of 
$$
(D^2+2D+5)y=e^{ix}.
$$
Using the unknown-coefficients approach set $y_p=Ce^{ix}$ to get
$$
(4+2i)Ce^{ix}=e^{ix}\implies C=\frac{2-i}{10}.
$$
Then $Im((2-i)e^{ix})=2\sin x+\cos x$, confirming your particular solution.

---

However, in your solution formula the homogeneous part is wrong, it is misssing the argument $x$ in the exponentials $e^{(1\pm 2i)x}$.

It would be slightly better if you wrote the homogeneous solution in its real form using the basis functions $e^x\cos 2x$ and $e^x\sin 2x$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving $m^2 - 2m + 5 = 0$ gives $m=1\pm 2i$ so the general solution is

$$ y = e^x(A\cos 2x + B\sin 2x) $$

The particular integral of $\sin x$ is of the form $y = \lambda\cos x + \mu\sin x$.

Therefore

$$ \begin{aligned} y &= \lambda\cos x + \mu\sin x \\ y' &= -\lambda\sin x + \mu\cos x \\ y'' &= - \lambda\cos x - \mu\sin x \end{aligned} $$

Substituting

$$ \left.\begin{aligned} - \lambda\cos x - \mu\sin x \\ -\: 2(-\lambda\sin x + \mu\cos x) \\ + \:5(\lambda\cos x + \mu\sin x)\end{aligned}\right\} = \sin x$$

$$ \left.\begin{aligned}(4\lambda - 2\mu)\cos x \\  + \: (2\lambda + 4\mu)\sin x \end{aligned}\right\} = \sin x $$

Comparing coefficients:

$$ \begin{cases}4\lambda - 2\mu = 0 \\ 2\lambda + 4\mu = 1\end{cases} $$

So $\lambda = \frac{1}{10}$ and $\mu=\frac{1}{5}$ so the particular integral is

$$ \frac{\cos x}{10} + \frac{\sin x}{5} $$

and the solution is

$$ y = e^x(A\cos 2x + B\sin 2x) + \frac{\cos x}{10} + \frac{\sin x}{5} $$

This is the same as your answer, after applying Euler's identity and simplifying.

Comment: Doesn't  e^2ix = Cos2x + iSin2x Then How come general solution is independent of i.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ImanVirk $A, B$ are just constants. so $B=i$ if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution $y$ of your equation $((D-1)^2+4)y=\sin x$ must satisfy
$$
            (D^2+1)((D-1)^2+4)y=0
$$
The general solution of the last equation is
$$
                  y = A\sin x + B\cos x+Ee^x\cos(2x)+Fe^{x}\sin(2x).
$$
The particular solution must come from the terms $A\sin x + B\cos x$ because the remaining terms are annihilated by $((D-1)^2+4)$. So, solve for $A,B$ such that
$$
                ((D-1)^2+4)(A\sin x + B\cos x)=\sin x \\
                (D^2-2D+1+4)(A\sin x + B\cos x)=\sin x \\
                (-2D+4)(A\sin x + B\cos x)=\sin x \\
                (2B+4A)\sin x + (-2A+4B)\cos x = \sin x \\
                         +4A+2B = 1 \\
                         -2A+4B = 0
$$
A particular solution is
$$
                   y_p = \frac{1}{5}\sin x +\frac{1}{10}\cos x.
$$